# Anchor/Fix a text in Bokeh to a figure's bounds

Tags: python, bokeh, styling

Is there a way to fix/anchor a text in a Bokeh figure to the active viewport?
Meaning that panning/zooming will not alter its position. This corresponds to the `position: fixed` option in CSS.

Should look something like:

```py
 p.text(x="figure.top", y="figure.left", text="some text", x_offset=10, y_offset=-10)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the `Text` glyph, but if you don't need a real glyph then you can use `Label` since it allows you to specify the units for its coordinates:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.add_layout(Label(x=0, x_units='screen', y=0, y_units='screen', text='Hello'))

show(p)
```